# How to extract SOAP header information from a JAX-WS class?

Tags: java, soap, header, jax-ws

I'm writing a JAX-WS WebService but I am running into a little stumbling block when it comes to extracting information from the SOAP header.  My WebService class is annotated with @WebService and I am inject the WebServiceContext into the class with:

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext webServiceContext;
```

but I'm a little stuck at this point as to how to extract the SOAP header information.

I'm using Spring 3, but haven't seen any methods/util classes there either that would shed some light on the issue.  From what I've seen online, I can use `getMessageContext()` and cast to a `SOAPMessageContext`, but I see significant numbers of people failing at that level complaining about casting problems with no offered solution.

I have not yet tried it, so before I did, I was wondering if this was the preferred method, or if there is a better technique to use.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you can get the SoapMessageContext with a message handler. You can check the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846121/changing-the-default-xml-namespace-prefix-generated-with-jaxws/4782059#4782059).

Implementing a SoapMessageHandler like this should work:

```
public class SoapHeadersHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
{

  @Override
  public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext)
  {
    try
    {
      Object[] headers = soapMessageContext.getHeaders(...);
    }
    catch (SOAPException e)
    {
      // Handle exception
    }

    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Posting here what I did, as it doesnt requires creating an extra class

```
final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) wsCtxt.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
String headerValue = req.getHeader("myHeaderName");
```