# Java get Response from SOAP service URL call

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

I want to get Response from request of SOAP URL. For this I am using below code

```
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Test {
    final static String UserLogin = "tuser01@xyz.com";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
            String url = "http://devlocal04:8080/arsys/WSDL/public/devlocal03/DAL:OrderShim_WS";
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);
            printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);
            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
        }
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        String serverURI = "urn:DAL:OrderShim_WS";
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("urn", serverURI);

        SOAPHeader soapHeader = envelope.getHeader();
        SOAPElement soapHeaderElem = soapHeader.addChildElement("AuthenticationInfo", "urn");
        SOAPElement soapHeaderElem1 = soapHeaderElem.addChildElement("userName", "urn");
        soapHeaderElem1.addTextNode("Test");
        SOAPElement soapHeaderElem2 = soapHeaderElem.addChildElement("password", "urn");
        soapHeaderElem2.addTextNode("12345");
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("Get_Order", "urn");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Login_Name", "urn");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode(UserLogin);
        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "Login_Name");

        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();
        return soapMessage;
    }

    private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    }
}
```

I have to do Request like below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:DAL:OrderShim_WS">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
         <urn:userName>Test</urn:userName>
         <urn:password>12345</urn:password>
      </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Get_Order>
         <urn:Login_Name>tuser01@xyz.com</urn:Login_Name>
      </urn:Get_Order>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But when I run my code they call this SOAP by using below Request

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:DAL:OrderShim_WS">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
            <urn:userName>Test</urn:userName>
            <urn:password>12345</urn:password>
        </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <urn:Get_Order>
            <urn:Login_Name>tuser01@xyz.com</urn:Login_Name>
        </urn:Get_Order>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In my request I can see "SOAP-ENV" in plcae of "soapenv" and I am not getting the valid response.

I am using Java 1.8.

Comment: SOAP-ENV is the default prefix used by Spring-WS See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242197/how-to-change-soap-env-default-prefix-of-spring-ws

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting this error because of SOAP-ENV.Replace SOAP-ENV with soapenv or make your request same as the required.You will get an idea from my code

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        soapMessage
                .getSOAPPart()
                .getEnvelope()
                .removeAttributeNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
                        "SOAP-ENV");
        soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope()
                .removeAttribute("xmlns:SOAP-ENV");
        soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().detachNode();
        soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setPrefix("soap");
        soapMessage.getSOAPBody().setPrefix("soap");

// envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ns1", serverURI);
// we need to send the soap request in the format mentioned below
/*
 * xmlInput =
 * "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n"
 * + "    <soap:Body>\r\n" +
 * "        <ns1:LoginProcesRequest xmlns:ns1=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/GetSFDCDetailsProcess\">\r\n"
 * + "           <ns1:Login>1000</ns1:Login>\r\n" +
 * "           <ns1:Company>1000</ns1:Company>\r\n" +
 * "        </ns1:LoginProcesRequest>\r\n" + "    </soap:Body>\r\n" +
 * "</soap:Envelope>";
 */

// SOAP Body
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement(
        "LoginProcesRequest", "ns1", serverURI);
SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem
        .addChildElement("Login", "ns1");
soapBodyElem1.addTextNode(inputlogin);
SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Company",
        "ns1");
soapBodyElem2.addTextNode(inputcompany);
MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "LoginProcesRequest");
soapMessage.saveChanges();
/* Print the request message */
System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
System.out.println();
```

You can explore this easily

Comment: Now I can POST exactly what I needed. But I am not able to get Valid Response. I am getting the whole WSDL in Response.

Comment: yes your code looks fine to me.try to hit your wsdl in browser directly by removing ?wsdl from wsdl url.you will see the xml request which you have to hit.Convert your request to same format and then run your code

Comment: Now I can get Response `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns0:Get_OrderResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:DAL:OrderShim_WS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ns0:OrderNumber>OrdNumber0011556</ns0:OrderNumber>
</ns0:Get_OrderResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>` Can you please help me to get `OrderNumber` from this Response.

Comment: make sure you write an exact xpath expression                                                              `DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
     .newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

   Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
     response)));

   XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
   XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

   string ordernumber= (String) xpath
     .evaluate(
       "/Envelope/Body/Get_Ord‌​erResponse/OrderNumber",
       doc, XPathConstants.STRING);`

Comment: convert your response in string and then pass it to docbuilder                                       `Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
  transformer.transform(sourceContent, new StreamResult(out));
  String response = out.toString();`

Comment: did you get yur answer?

Comment: Yes. I got my answer.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. But its useful for me So I accept it as Useful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an easy way to solve this. Make sure to set the prefix of the elements that come back by default with SOAP-ENV.

```
SOAPHeader soapHeader = envelope.getHeader();
soapHeader.setPrefix("soapenv");
```

You can do the same for the soapBody. You may still get the extra namespace declation at the top but the prefix will no longer be used