# JAva SOAP: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, soap

I've seen questions like this but so far they don't help.

I'm currently having an issue setting a prefix for an element within my SOAP body.
The request I'm trying to build looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sen="http://company.org/sendmailaTTACH">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sen:SendMail>
         <sen:plainbody>?</sen:plainbody>
      </sen:SendMail>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Was able to build it to the point of the `SendMail` object by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43316912/5038073), but when it gets to the part of adding the prefix: `<sen:plainbody>` i.e adding the `sen` prefix to `plainbody` I get the error:

> org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create
>   or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to
>   namespaces.

The `SendMail` object looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
        name = "",
        propOrder = {"from", "displayname", "to", "cc", "bcc", "htmlbody", "plainbody", "subject", "imageurl"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
        name = "SendMail"
)
public class SendMail {
    protected String from;
    protected String displayname;
    protected String to;
    protected String cc;
    protected String bcc;
    protected String htmlbody;
    protected String plainbody;
    protected String subject;
    protected String imageurl;

    public SendMail() {
    }
.
.
.
//getters and setters
```

I'm guessing maybe it's because the plainbody and other fields there are String?

Is there any way around this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution:

Was able to work around it by annotating the class properties with `@XmlElement` and specifying the namespace

```
@XmlElement(namespace = "http://company.org/sendmailaTTACH")
protected String from;

@XmlElement(namespace = "http://company.org/sendmailaTTACH")
protected String displayname;

@XmlElement(namespace = "http://company.org/sendmailaTTACH")
protected String to;

@XmlElement(namespace = "http://company.org/sendmailaTTACH")
protected String cc;

@XmlElement(namespace = "http://company.org/sendmailaTTACH")
protected String bcc;

@XmlElement(namespace = "http://company.org/sendmailaTTACH")
protected String htmlbody;

@XmlElement(namespace = "http://company.org/sendmailaTTACH")
protected String plainbody;

@XmlElement(namespace = "http://company.org/sendmailaTTACH")
protected String subject;

@XmlElement(namespace = "http://company.org/sendmailaTTACH")
protected String imageurl;
```